# swift build doesn't work

Tags: swift, xcode-tools, kitura

I'm trying to run [Kitura](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura) project on XCode. I tried to follow instructions on this page ([https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura/wiki/Building-your-Kitura-application-on-XCode]), however I failed with step 3 – run `swift build -X`. I get this error:

```
error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build (No such file or directory)
```

Looks like I have latest toolchain installed (see the screenshot below). [image]
I also have both XCode 7.3.1 and XCode 8 beta. What would you suggest to solve that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of this writing, Kitura only compiles with the 06-06 Swift Development toolchain so make sure you have that installed.

In addition the wiki was out of date, the generate Xcode project command got renamed to `swift package generate-xcodeproj`. I updated the wiki to reflect this change.

Comment: Thank you for answer! However, your suggested command fails too. I got this error:

Comment: <unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.11.sdk'
error: exit(1): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-06-20-a.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc --driver-mode=swift -I /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-06-20-a.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm -L /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-06-20-a.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm -lPackageDescription -target x86_64-apple-macosx10.10 /Users/alexander/kitura_photo_test/Package.swift -fileno 4

Comment: I've heard that XCode 8 beta has had trouble running on El Capitan so try using XCode 7.3.1 if you haven't already. Also it looks like from that error that the 06-20 toolchain is still being used. In the menu bar go to XCode -> Toolchains and select the 06-06 snapshot.

Answer (score 11):

As Daniel mentioned above, Kitura right now requires use of the June 6 drop of the Swift Development toolchain.  This toolchain can only be used with Xcode v7.3.1.  The toolchain format changed between Xcode 7.x and newer Xcode 8 beta.  When using the Xcode 8 beta with the new June 20 toolchain, there's another step that you need to do before you can run `swift build` from the command line.

From the command line, enter the following command:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/
```

This command is necessary to inform Xcode where to find the required binaries and frameworks.

To switch it back, just use the same command but point it at non-beta version of Xcode:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Using these commands will eliminate the error `<unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.11.sdk' error: exit(1):` that you ran into.

The Xcode 8 beta will be required to be used for all future Swift.org toolchains unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me to find `swift package`